# How to set up a jail network in FreeBSD13.2

Tags: networking, freebsd

I'm trying to build a toy network on a small server running FreeBSD 13.2. The idea is that I would have a few jails running web services that I could connect to from outside, which would then connect to databases running in other jails. I'm following [this guide to vnet and jails](https://weblog.antranigv.am/posts/2020/06/vnet-jail-howto/) which attempts to be a simple working example for getting started, which results in this less than helpful error message.

```
# jail -c mysql
epair10a
jail: mysql: vnet jails cannot have IP address restrictions
```

My lightly edited version of `/etc/jail.conf` is at the bottom of this post. No amount of futzing with `ip4=inherit;`, `ip4=new;`, or `ip4=default;` has any other result. I've checked the freebsd forum [this post has a person who claims to have solved the same error](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/jail-jailname-vnet-jails-cannot-have-ip-address-restrictions.89257/), but they use some packages that I can't get through `pkg`. (I suspect they wouldn't help anyways).

I'm clearly missing *something* but it's been hard to find anything *that* useful for jail networking.

```
#/etc/jail.conf
# 1. definition of variables that we'll use through the config file
$jail_path="/jails";
path="$jail_path/$name";

# 2. begin - default configuration for all jails

# 3. some applications might need access to devfs
mount.devfs;

# 4. Clear environment variables
exec.clean;

# 5. Use the host's network stack for all jails
# ip4=inherit;
# ip6=inherit;

# 6. Initialization scripts
exec.start="sh /etc/rc";
exec.stop="sh /etc/rc.shutdown";

# 7. specific jail configuration   
mysql {

        $id = "10";
        $ipaddr = "10.17.0.${id}";
        $mask = "255.255.255.0";
        $gw = "10.17.0.1";

        vnet;
        vnet.interface = "epair${id}b";

        exec.prestart = "ifconfig epair${id} create up";
        exec.prestart += "ifconfig epair${id}a up descr vnet-${name}";
        exec.prestart += "ifconfig bridge0 addm epair${id}a up";

        exec.start = "/sbin/ifconfig lo0 127.0.0.1 up";
        exec.start += "/sbin/ifconfig epair${id}b ${ipaddr} netmask ${mask} up";
        exec.start += "/sbin/route add default ${gw}";
        exec.start += "/bin/sh /etc/rc";

        exec.prestop = "ifconfig epair${id}b -vnet ${name}";

        exec.poststop = "ifconfig bridge0 deletem epair${id}a";
        exec.poststop += "ifconfig epair${id}a destroy";

        path="/jails/mysql";
        host.hostname = "${name}";

        exec.consolelog = "/var/log/jail-${name}.log";

}
```

Comment: Define one end of the epair in your host machine's rc.conf, set it to up, and define the other end of the epair in your jail.conf and set it to up. Here's a much better Jail tutorial `https://freebsdfoundation.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Jail-vnet-by-Examples.pdf`